# I barely have any friends!

Tags: grammar

I (non-native speaker) keep stumbling over things such as "barely has any influence". It seems to me that in these examples *any* is redundant. Shouldn't : "I barely have friends" be sufficient? And is the combination of *barely* and *any* as above considered to be grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Barely and any can fit perfectly in a sentence. **Barely** described something that is possible but with difficulty or as in the example below, almost doesn't happen. It's an *adverb*.
**Any** on the other hand indicates an amount. It's a *determiner*. So Two different things.

```
 2 in a way that almost does not happen or exist
     She barely acknowledged his presence.
     There was barely any smell.
```

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/barely

P.S.: this is more speculation on my side since I'm not an English teacher or know the details of the English language but using "any" or not does give a different "feel" to your sentence:

1. I barely have **any** friends.
2. I barely have friends.

By using any in the first sentence you almost automatically put an emphasis on the fact that you have almost no one you can call "friends" **at all**. In the second sentence there is less emphasis on this fact. Though please correct me.